# construct FailSafe.dev RetryPolicy based on condition

Tags: spring-rest

I use Spring WebClient calling REST API, retry in case of retrieving empty response, how do I construct Retry Policy to archive this goal

```
Failsafe.with(RetryPolicy.builder()
    .handleResultIf(response -> response.getData().isEmpty())
    .withDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(2)).withMaxAttempts(5).build())
    .get(() -> client.getResponse();
```

I tried to use handleResultIf, but response is not the JSON object returned from API call, so response.getData() failed to compile